# Add multiple css classes to a WFFM Field

Tags: css, class, sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

How I can add multiple CSS class into a SingleLine WFFM field.I have to assign unique class name into each WFFM field and fill the field value via Class selector by Jquery.

I want to keep use the default css class name + add custom class.

Answer (score 1):

I Created Custom Class "/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Meta data/Css Classes" and added multiple class name by giving space inside  **Value** Field. e.g. **class1 class2 class3**